# Text categorization. How to count word occurrences in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, python

I have excel sheets that contain written reviews of apartment complexes. Currently my team and I go through the reviews by hand and color code sentences by certain complaint categories. Ex. Noise, smoke, communication, maintenance, etc.

I would like to automate this process because for thousands of properties it is extremely time consuming to do every week.

I would like to count the occurrences for specific words, or word categories and use those to automatically color code the review. It might be nice to also count those words per sentence, as aspects of the review (complaint or compliment topic) is usually contained in one sentence.

An advanced solution could learn new words over time by itself but that would probably require a more advanced program in python or something. Any input would be much appreciated because my background is not in machine learning or computer science. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Marcus, welcome. Unfortunately you have to narrow your question down in this forum. The idea is to ask specific questions in a generic way so that other users with similar problems can benefit from the communal knowledge generated in the answers. Opinion based questions like "what is best" or even "conceptual" solutions don't suit this forum well. That being said, I edited your question to be more excel specific, as I believe you can simplify your workflow considerably with just a few good formulas. Not a whole machine learning algorithm though, but helpful.

Comment: The idea would be to define a name (Formulas > Define Name), call it "NoiseWords" and set it to refer to e.g. `={"loud";"nois";"roudy";"siren"}`. Now with the review text in A2, **select cell B2** next to it and define a new name (this selection is NB as we are defining the name relative to the cell on the left). Call it "CountNoise" and set refer to as `=SUM((LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,NoiseWords,"")))/LEN(NoiseWords))`. Now in B2 put `=CountNoise`. It will count all occurrences of the words defined in NoiseWords. Do the same for all other word categories.

Comment: A more advanced method could be based off of your existing tagged data. Excel has an add-on called Fuzzy Lookup, which compares two text cells and provides a similarity score. In theory you could group your existing data into e.g. "noisy"/"smoke"/"maintenance" type sentences, then use those as input in Fuzzy to provide a similarity score. Scores would be quite low (score of 1 = two exact same sentences) but might still be sufficient to use for categorization. Note this idea is untested and perhaps commonly occurring words like "unhappy" or "the" or "good" might sway the scoring. Worth a try?